# Getting information from a 15 Giant Avail Adv 1 Serial Number

Tags: frames, serial-number

My bike was totaled.  I have the serial number from the original receipt.  Can I find out the frame size of the bike with the serial number?

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. It is nearly impossible to identify a bicycle without pictures.  A serial number is rarely useable to identify much about a bicycle.  If the original receipt does not have the frame size, then you would have to make an educated guess based on your height, etc.  If it has not been too long, the bike shop where you purchased the bicycle may have a record of the size.

Comment: Sounds like it'd be worth emailing Giant with the information you have.